# Is there a quick way to extract the word after 'hi' from a column in dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

My data is like:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'aa':['hi asf afe','hi a fefe','hi fefavfv av'],
               'b':['faef af af  asf fef','1 1 1','greg fd']})
```

What I want is extract the word after 'hi' (maybe it is a name) from the column aa. Here is my way:

```
import re
def myTry(Str):
    g=re.search('hi (.*?) ',Str)
    return g.group(1)

a.loc[:,'Try']=a.apply(lambda x: myTry(x['aa']),axis=1)
```

the result is correct. But I have to define a function here. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.extract` as follows:

```
a.aa.str.extract(r'hi +\b(\w+)\b')

Out[133]:
         0
0      asf
1        a
2  fefavfv
```

---

If you insist on using `str.split`. A simple default split and picking 2nd element is enough

```
a.aa.str.split().str[1]

Out[134]:
0        asf
1          a
2    fefavfv
Name: aa, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'aa':['hi asf afe','hi a fefe','hi fefavfv av'],
               'b':['faef af af  asf fef','1 1 1','greg fd']})
#a['bb'] = a['aa'].str.split('hi').str.get(1).str.strip()
# To keep first word after 'hi'
a['bb'] = a['aa'].str.split('hi').str.get(1).str.strip().str.split(' ').str.get(0)
a
```

Output:

```
        aa          b                   bb
0   hi asf afe  faef af af asf fef      asf
1   hi a fefe   1 1 1                     a
2   hi fefavfv av   greg fd         fefavfv
```

Comment: hi, Thanks a lot. But I just want to keep one word after 'hi'. Here are two words are kept.